# How to display available quantity of each product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, php-7, stock-status

I want available stock Qty to be displayed right underneath of the home page and quick view like I have marked on,what would be the easiest approach to achieve this?
(I use an advanced warehouse module to maintain 25 different store views at particular locations[Amasty Advanced Inventory])

[image: Home page]
[image: Quick view]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261246/how-do-i-show-child-product-quantity-inside-a-config-grouped-product/

Answer (score 2):

to Show quantity on listing page and quick show pop you there are 2 methods either create your custom module and call its block on both places or add code directly using $ObjectManager.

This method is not recommended but since you need some quick and easy solution that is why I am giving it here :

```
<?php
    $ObjectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $StockState = $ObjectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');

    echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
 ?>
```

for adding on listing page Go to your theme folder**Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml** file and add below code where you want to show it i.e underneath product name etc.

**Same you can add code to your theme's quick view template.**